# Wi-fi issues on Dell Vostro 3446 Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, dell-vostro

I installed Ubuntu 14.04(Trusty Tahr) on my Dell Vostro 3446 and it seems to work fine barring a glitch.
The wi-fi does not work. When I click the wi-fi button on the top right, it does not show nearby networks.
Networking is on and nearby wi-fi networks DO exist. It leads me to think that it might be a driver issue.
Wi-fi works fine on the dual-booted Windows 8.1.
If it is, where can I find something for Ubuntu? If not, what other tests should I run to determine the issue?

*The lspci output is as follows*

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)  
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)  
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)  
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)  
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)  
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)  
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)  
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)  
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)  
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)  
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)  
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)  
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)  
06:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)  
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)  
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: Have you installed the necessary drivers? What's the output of `lspci`and `rfkill list all`?

Comment: lspci lists a Network controller and an Ethernet controller. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Absolutely sounds like a driver issue. Try searching your wifi hardware with linux on the end and seeing which driver others use with that setup.

Comment: the one for wireless. Post the output here

Comment: There is none for wireless.

Comment: Looks like it just isn't installed correctly. Look for a device that calls itself something like wnp2s0. These devices (using a similar format of letters and numbers) generally represent network devices. Could you include the output of lspci? that would help in identifying whether the kernel even sees the wifi card.

Comment: Put it up in a question edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct driver for your Broadcom can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If you have just installed Ubuntu 14.04, do a sudo apt-get update first.

Reboot and let us know the result.

If you still have the install DVD or USB, then you can find it and its prerequisite there. Navigate to pool > restricted > b > bcmwl and drag and drop the deb file to your desktop. Now navigate to pool > main > d > dkms and drag and drop dkms to your desktop. Now install both with:

```
cd ~/Desktop
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe wl
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: While I go hunting for an ethernet cable, is there any way I could download the correct driver onto a different laptop and transfer it to this?

Comment: Do you still have the install DVD or USB?

Comment: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.141+bdcom-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb

Comment: @solsTiCe Does he have a 64-bit system? What about the several dependencies?

Comment: yes. I know. I can't do all his/her job

Comment: by the way what is the difference betwenn *bcmwl-kernel-source* and *broadcom-sta-dkms* ? They seem to use the same source and use dkms, so ...

Comment: @chili555 It worked like a charm and the listing of wifi networks is now up.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't connect to internet by a cable, you may want to get this driver from the installation Ubuntu media (flash or DVD).

Insert Ubuntu installation disk or flash drive and browse it.
Download two files from there to your home folder.

pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_XXXXX.deb

pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_XXXXX.deb

Then run in terminal

sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu 14.04 you dont need to do sudo apt-get update, only the driver installation will do using the command that chilli told about

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

And wifi is activated instantly, no need to reboot. It has helped me a lot on vostro 3446 whenever using live cd of ubuntu.

Comment: Depending on the state of the computer, the update ensures a 100% working solution.

Comment: Yes, it worked till Ubuntu 14.04, and requires update in 15.10

Answer (score -1):

Problem still exists on Ubuntu 16.04 and my Vostro 1310 laptop. None of the above solutions was working for me so to solve the problem i ordered a "whatever brand" super cheap 2$US WiFicard that did not have the broadcom chip on it. I replaced the existing card (located under harddrive) and voila, everything works normal.
Extra info: The Vostro has 3 cables for WiFi only 2 are connected on the broadcom (the gray cable is insulated). Be sure to connect all 3 in the right order (white-black-gray) on the new card. These are the antenna wires, if you forget to put on the gray cable you might recieve WiFi but you are unable to connect

SOLVED